# string.Format throwing exception

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have an issue with String.Format that I need assistance with:

```
string Placeholder = @"(function({0}, $, undefined) { {1} }( window.{0} = window.{0} || {}, jQuery));";
string output = string.Format(Placeholder, "Value1", "Value2");
```

The following exception is thorwn at String.Format

'string.Format(Placeholder, "Value1", "Value2")' threw an exception of type 'System.FormatException'    string {System.FormatException}

Any idea why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because of the braces: `{ {1} }` and `|| {}`. Use doubles:

```
string Placeholder = @"(function({0}, $, undefined) {{ {1} }}( window.{0} = window.{0} || {{}}, jQuery));";
string output = string.Format(Placeholder, "Value1", "Value2");
```

http://geekswithblogs.net/jonasb/archive/2007/03/05/108023.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Probably the `{` brackets you have in there.  Try doubling up the ones that don't surround a token to be replaced.

Like so:

```
string Placeholder = @"(function({0}, $, undefined) {{ {1} }}( window.{0} = window.{0} || {{}}, jQuery));";
string output = string.Format(Placeholder, "Value1", "Value2");
```